# Excel VBA - Application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am new to VBA scripting. I have developed a code to export data to XML file with predefined structure. When I run it, I am getting an error Application defined or object defined error. I am not sure how debug this as system does not highlight the issue. Could you please help me identify the issues and make required changes?

Thank you

```
Option Explicit
'Private Const ColDocDate As String = "DocDate"
'Private Const ColDocNum As String = "DocNum"
'Private Const ColCorrSyntAcc As String = "CorrSyntAcc"
'Private Const ColPayerSettAcc As String = "PayerSettAcc"
'Private Const ColReceiverName As String = "ReceiverName"
'Private Const ColReceiverSettlementAccount As String = "ReceiverSettlementAccount"
'Private Const ColCurrencyCode As String = "CurrencyCode"
'Private Const ColAmount As String = "Amount"
'Private Const ColPartnerCode As String = "PartnerCode"
'Private Const ColPaymentAim As String = "PaymentAim"
'Private Const ColTransactionDate As String = "TransactionDate"
Private Const ColDocDate As String = "A"
Private Const ColDocNum As String = "B"
Private Const ColCorrSyntAcc As String = "I"
Private Const ColPayerSettAcc As String = "D"
Private Const ColReceiverName As String = "G"
Private Const ColReceiverSettlementAccount As String = "H"
Private Const ColCurrencyCode As String = "E"
Private Const ColAmount As String = "J"
Private Const ColPartnerCode As String = "F"
Private Const ColPaymentAim As String = "K"
Private Const ColTransactionDate As String = "C"

Sub ExportToXML()
Dim oPaymOrders     As DOMDocument
Dim FName           As String
Dim sError          As String
On Error GoTo Err
 'create oPaymOrders
    Set oPaymOrders = New DOMDocument
        
    Call GenerateXML(oPaymOrders)
    FName = "PaymentOrders.xml"
        
ShowDlgSaveAS:
    FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FName, _
                "XML Files (*.xml),*.xml", 1, "Save As")
    
    If Dir(FName) <> "" Then
        If MsgBox(prompt:=Dir(FName) & " already exists." & vbCrLf _
                        & "Do you want to replace it?", Buttons:=vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            GoTo ShowDlgSaveAS
        End IF
    End If    
    If FName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call XMLToFile(oPaymOrders, FName)
    Exit Sub

Err:
    sError = Err.Description
 
    MsgBox sError, vbCritical
End Sub

Public Sub XMLToFile(ByVal xmlDoc As Object, ByVal FileName As String)
Dim wrt As New MXXMLWriter
Dim rdr As New SAXXMLReader
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim stream As TextStream
Dim sXml As String
Dim btXMLInBytes() As Byte
Dim lFile As Long
Dim fFile As File

    Set rdr.contentHandler = wrt
    Set rdr.dtdHandler = wrt
    Set rdr.errorHandler = wrt
    wrt.indent = True
    wrt.omitXMLDeclaration = False
    wrt.Version = "1.0"
    rdr.Parse xmlDoc
    
    sXml = wrt.output
    sXml = Replace(sXml, "encoding=""UTF-16""", "encoding=""UTF-8""")
    btXMLInBytes = UniStrToUTF8(sXml)
    
    If fso.FileExists(FileName) Then '
        Set fFile = fso.GetFile(FileName)
        fFile.Delete True
    End If
    
    lFile = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Binary Access Write As lFile
    Put lFile, , btXMLInBytes
    Close lFile
End Sub


Public Sub GenerateXML(oPaymOrders As DOMDocument)
Dim FirstRow            As Long
Dim Count               As Long
Dim i                   As Long
Dim ErrCount            As Long
Dim oPaymOrder          As IXMLDOMElement
Dim oExchange           As IXMLDOMElement
Dim oElement            As IXMLDOMElement
Dim oManualEntriesList  As IXMLDOMElement
Dim DocTotalSumm        As Currency

    
    With Sheets("PayOrderGroupImport")
        FirstRow = .Range("DocDate").Row + 1
        
        'Exchange
        Set oExchange = oPaymOrders.createElement("Exchange")
        oExchange.setAttribute "xmlns", "http://wwww"
        oPaymOrders.appendChild oExchange
        
        Do While Trim$(.Range(ColDocDate & CStr(FirstRow))) <> ""
            Count = CountOfEntries(FirstRow)
            If Count > 0 Then
                'oPaymOrders
                Set oPaymOrder = oPaymOrders.createElement("PayOrd")
                oPaymOrder.setAttribute "xmlns:i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                oExchange.appendChild oPaymOrder
                
                'IsDraft
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("IsDraft")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = "false"
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
            
                'DocHasSystemEntries
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("DocHasSystemEntries")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = "false"
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
                
                'ManualEntriesList
                Set oManualEntriesList = oPaymOrders.createElement("ManualEntriesList")
                'oPaymOrder.appendChild oManualEntriesList
                
                'DocumentDate
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("DocumentDate")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = Format(.Range(ColDocDate & CStr(i - 1)), "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00")
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
                
                'DocumentNumber
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("DocumentNumber")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColDocNum & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement

                'CorrSyntAcc
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("CorrSyntAcc")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColCorrSyntAcc & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
                
                'PayerName
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("PayerName")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = "X"
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
                
                'PayerSettlementAccount
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("PayerSettlementAccount")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColPayerSettAcc & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement

                'PayerTaxCode
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("PayerTaxCode")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = "X"
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement

                'ReceiverName
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("ReceiverName")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColReceiverName & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement

                'ReceiverSettlementAccount
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("ReceiverSettlementAccount")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColReceiverSettlementAccount & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
                
                'ReceiverTaxCode
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("ReceiverTaxCode")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = "X"
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
                
                'CurrencyCode
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("CurrencyCode")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColCurrencyCode & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
                
                'Amount
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("Amount")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColAmount & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement

                'PartnerCode
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("PartnerCode")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColPartnerCode & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
                
                'PaymentAim
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("PaymentAim")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = (Trim$(.Range(ColPaymentAim & CStr(i - 1))))
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement

                'TransactionDate
                Set oElement = oPaymOrders.createElement("TransactionDate")
                oElement.nodeTypedValue = Format(.Range(ColTransactionDate & CStr(i - 1)), "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00")
                oPaymOrder.appendChild oElement
            End If
            DocTotalSumm = 0
            FirstRow = FirstRow + Count
        Loop
    
    End With
End Sub
Function CountOfEntries(ByVal FirstRow As Long) As Long
Dim NextRow As Long

    NextRow = FirstRow + 1
    
    With Sheets("PayOrderGroupImport")
        Do While True
            If Trim$(.Cells(FirstRow, ColDocDate).Value) = Trim$(.Cells(NextRow, ColDocDate).Value) And _
               Trim$(.Cells(FirstRow, ColDocNum).Value) = Trim$(.Cells(NextRow, ColDocNum).Value) Then
                NextRow = NextRow + 1
            Else
                CountOfEntries = NextRow - FirstRow
                Exit Function
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: An error that doesn't highlight a line of code usually occurs because a declaration can't be executed. Perhaps the DLL for the `DOMDocument` isn't loaded (which I doubt) or there is an argument error deep in the code, meaning in the function call within the sub of a sub of a sub. An "argument error" would be a mismatch between the argument given and the parameter received, perhaps an object passed Byval or a Double assigned to a Variant ByRef. Limit the scope of possibilities by remming out large chunks of code and progressively enabling them again.

Comment: Far too much code. Please trim it down to a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.  That [mre] should not include commented out code. Expecting us to wade through that much code is simply not reasonable. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: In procedure `GenerateXML` occurs a variable `i` without assigned value (default: 0) thus resulting in a negative value starting at section `'DocumentDate`. Side note to XML: I'd prefer the current *Microsoft XML, vers. 6* library plus document declarations as `DOMDocument60`

Answer (score 0):

If your introduction, saying that you are new to VBA, is to be taken at face value your achievement is truly remarkable. Let me introduce you to Enums (enumeriations). Here is a replacement for your block of constants declared in your code.

```
Enum Col                        ' column IDs
    ColDocDate = 1
    ColDocNum
    ColTransactionDate
    ColPayerSettAcc
    ColCurrencyCode
    ColPartnerCode
    ColReceiverName
    ColReceiverSettlementAccount
    ColCorrSyntAcc
    ColAmount
    ColPaymentAim
End Enum
```

Enumerations are the most efficient way VBA has to assign names to integers. However, there are a few systems at work here that you need to know. The first one is that you can assign any number to any name but if you assign no value the value given is the one of the preceding enumeration plus 1. Therefore, since you see `1` assigned to the first enum and none to the following they are just counting up. 1 = column A and the last one 11 = column K. If you were to insert a column at *ColPartnerCode* you could just assign a different number there or insert an extra name. It's much more flexible than constants.

Enums must be declared at the top of the module before any procedures. They are *Public* by default but you could declare it *Private* to limit its scope to the current module. Enums are of Long datatype by nature and interchangable with numbers of Long datatype. But if you declare `Dim MyLong As Col` you will get assistance from intellisense.

The full name of an enum consists of the "family" name and the enumeration name, like `Col.ColDocDate` (`Col` being the "family"). This method of naming is reminiscent of how VBA names enumerations. They all start with xl, vb, wd or mso but these aren't "family names" as much as they are identifiers. `xlRight` is an enumeration which you can use anywhere in your (Excel) code without ever knowing the "family" name. It's the same for `ColDocDate`. The scope is determined by the declaration, either private or public [default].

Therefore, if you replace your constants with my enums the only problem you will have to face is the conversion from string to long. In code like `Cells(R, ColDocDate)` the conversion is done by Excel. But if you have syntax like `Range(ColDocDate & R)`, frankly, then you are probably better advised to keep this knowledge for your next project.

Comment: Thank you Variatus for such a detailed response. I will try to digest and try solution advised and will post the status. This is really my first VBA project. I had to read a lot and used some samples provided by others.